# Difference between Arrays & Single-Dimensional Arrays in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

What is the difference between Arrays & Single-Dimensional Arrays in c#?

Comment: This is like asking what is the difference between fruits and apples.

Comment: I think he may be asking about the difference between `Array digits;` and `int[] digits;`

Comment: Stevo I think your right, makes sense and Marc has a good explanation of that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays such as `int[]` or `int[,]` inherit from `Array` as the base class. The main difference is that `Array` only offers non-specific access, where-as *specific* arrays (such as a single-dimension array, `SomeType[]`) offer direct (and typed) indexer support via the compiler etc. This allows for more efficient usage, especially as the JIT can optimise this in many cases (removing bounds checks, etc).

`Array` is useful if you need to be able to use *any* type of array (without any specific type or dimension) - although to be honest this is rare, and with generics in 2.0 onwards, it is more common to see generic methods like `Foo<T>(T[])` or `Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`.

Answer (score 7):

What exactly is your question? Please specify. For now here are the different types of [Arrays in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Single-dimensional arrays:

```
int[] numbers;
```

Multidimensional arrays:

```
string[,] names;
```

Array-of-arrays (jagged):

```
byte[][] scores;
```

Answer (score 3):

[Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(VS.71).aspx) is a general term refering to various types of arrays in C# ([Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0(VS.71).aspx) Dimension, [Multi-Dimension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(VS.71).aspx) or [Jagged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca(VS.71).aspx)).

Single Dimension arrays are just one specific type of array in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays can be multi-dimensional or single-dimensional; single-dimensional arrays can only be single-dimensional.

If you want a meaningful answer, ask a meaningful question.

For much much more information, read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx).

You might be trying to ask what the difference between `MDARRAY`s and `SZARRAY`s is (see the above article).

`SZARRAY`s are zero-based, one dimensional arrays (inlcuding nested arrays, such as `int[][][][]`).  The runtime is highly optimized to maximize performance for `SZARRAY`s.

All other arrays (non-zero-based arrays, which are not supported by C#, and multi-dimensional arrays) are `MDARRAY`s, which aren't as fast.

Answer (score 1):

The same difference between rectangles and squares.

Comment: this answer i can say but why are you not write answer about my question

Comment: Because your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @clouserw: This is actually a serious answer. Every single-dimensional array is an array, but not every array is a single-dimensional array. The same is true for squares and rectangles.